# How to print a POS receipt from Sale Order?

Tags: javascript, xml, odoo, odoo-8, odoo-9

I need to print POS receipt from sale order with same products qty etc.

In Sale order I have created a button "Print POS receIpt". with this button  I want to trigger a method that prints out a receipt with sale order lines on it.

So I need to find the method that creates POS receipts and pass the sale order line values to it.

So which method is printing receipts in POS and how can I trigger it? Is it in `models.js`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In those Odoo versions, the receipts that are being printed in the POS are a screen capture (actually only the receipt div) made by JavaScript. But you cannot use this approach on the Sale Order view.

However, there is another way to print tickets into PDF with a normal Qweb Report. If you click on the POS menu you will find the "Orders" menu option on the left margin. You will have the print option under the "Print" menu on the form and list view.

[image: print receipt]

If you go to the `point_of_sale` module you will find the `report_receipt.xml` file written with the Qweb language. You can customize it to make it work with the `sale.order` model. But take into account that the paperformat should be `point_of_sale.paperformat_posreceipt`, you will find the paperformat assigment at the bottom of these code:

```xml
<template id="report_receipt">
    <t t-call="report.html_container">
        <t t-foreach="docs" t-as="o">
            <div class="page">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 text-center">
                        <h2 t-esc="o.user_id.company_id.name"/>
                        <div t-field="o.partner_id"
                            t-field-options='{"widget": "contact", "fields": ["address", "name", "phone", "fax"], "no_marker": true}'/>
                        User: <span t-field="o.user_id"/><br/>
                        Date: <span t-field="o.date_order"/><br/>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="row">
                </div>

                <table class="table table-condensed">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Description</th>
                            <th class="text-right">Quantity</th>
                            <th class="text-right">Price</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr t-foreach="o.lines" t-as="line">
                            <td><span t-field="line.product_id"/></td>
                            <td class="text-right">
                                <t t-if="o.state != 'cancel' and o.statement_ids">
                                    <span t-field="line.qty"/>
                                </t>
                            </td>
                            <td class="text-right">
                                <t t-if="o.state != 'cancel' and o.statement_ids">
                                    <span t-esc="formatLang(net(line.id), currency_obj=res_company.currency_id)"/>
                                </t>
                                <t t-if="line.discount != 0.0">
                                    <span t-esc="line.discount"/>%
                                </t>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 pull-right">
                        <table class="table table-condensed">
                            <tr class="border-black">
                                <td><strong>Taxes</strong></td>
                                <td class="text-right">
                                    <strong t-esc="formatLang(o.amount_tax, currency_obj=res_company.currency_id)"/>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><strong>Total</strong></td>
                                <td class="text-right">
                                    <strong t-esc="formatLang(o.amount_total, currency_obj=res_company.currency_id)"/>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <table class="table table-condensed">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Payment Mode</th>
                            <th>Amount</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr t-foreach="get_journal_amt(o)" t-as="d">
                            <td>
                                <span t-esc="d['name']"/>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <span t-esc="formatLang(d['amt'], currency_obj=res_company.currency_id)"/>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </t>
    </t>
</template>

<report
    id="action_report_pos_receipt"
    string="Receipt"
    model="pos.order"
    report_type="qweb-pdf"
    name="point_of_sale.report_receipt"
    file="point_of_sale.report_receipt"
/>

<record id="action_report_pos_receipt" model="ir.actions.report.xml">
    <field name="paperformat_id" ref="point_of_sale.paperformat_posreceipt"/>
</record>
```

Comment: You are mentioning version 8 and 9 but what about version 14? Does that still use this same way of generating the POS ticket? In the POS orders view I can't find this "Print" feature so the method above seems to be no longer valid.

Comment: I don't know. But, since version 10 POS module has been changed a lot. All the JS code is at least different. Anyway, you can check for the PDF template in the module, that is easy to find if it exists (or you may need to install another module). Anyway take a look at my first paragraph in the answer, that's maybe the only way that is being printed now. Let me know if you find the way, though I have been very disconnected from Odoo these latest years @th3