# Print receipt in pos order odoo

Tags: odoo-13, pos

I want to print receipt in pos order not only in pos session. Can I print receipt or report like pos session receipt.[image]

Above image, I want to print receipt in pos order form that are the same format with pos receipt.

Comment: Yes you can by customizing the existing template or by adding your own. This will also help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51633901/how-to-print-a-pos-receipt-from-sale-order

Comment: I don't see the paperformat of pos receipt.How can I find?